# What is causing images to skew left on my WP page?

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm making a website on WP, and I'm using Visual Composer. No blog, just pages. For some reason any images I put on the page skew left. When I load the page, initially the image is in the right place. But then immediately as the page loads they are pushed left. Even if they're inside of a row, as seen here:
[image: a print screen]

The image is inside the same row as the text, yet the text is correctly aligned, and the image is skewed. I put a border around the picture and you can see it even skews from the border.

I'm using the page inspector to try and figure out what in the stylesheet could be causing this, but I've already disabled/changed `max-width`. The `margin-left` for some reason says `-150` and I can't change it, the inspector keeps saying that even though I've changed to `0` it both on the Stylesheet Editor and in Customize -> Additional CSS.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Could you share an URL of the website so we can inspect?

Comment: Here, [a page with an image](http://www.litoraltotal.com/a-casa-28/).

Comment: Everything seems fine to me, try to "hard refresh" the browser. I'm using Chrome and the image is within the dots.

Comment: It turns out that the plugin Jetpack was causing the issues. After a whole day trying to solve this, uninstalling the plugin did it.

Comment: Great, I like the cleanliness and the design idea of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but it turns out that the solution was to get rid of the Jetpack plugin. It was causing issues with images and sliders. Everything's back to normal.